# How to get a specific EntityManager programmatically without using @PersistenceContext annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, applicationcontext

I have two different EntityManagers I want to use in a **legacy class (no bean)**  from its related **EntityManagerFactory**

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "entityManagerFactoryA") 
EntityManager entityManagerA;

@PersistenceContext(name = "entityManagerFactoryB") 
EntityManager entityManagerB;
```

I've tried to use **getBean()**

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

applicationContext.getBean("entityManagerFactoryA");
```

which results in this error:

> Cannot cast 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167' to 'java.persistence.EntityManager'

So currently wrapping the usual injection via **@PersistenceContext**  into a wrapper bean, which then is fetched from the **ApplicationContext** works

```
@Getter
@Component
private class EntityManagerAWrapper {

     @PersistenceContext(name = "entityManagerFactoryA")
     EntityManager entityManagerA;
}

.
.
.

applicationContext.getBean(EntityManagerAWrapper.class).getEntityManagerA();
```

This however is an unnesessary "hack" that I want to avoid. Is there any chance to get the correct EntityManager in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it like this:

```java
    EntityManagerFactory factory = 
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting Exception: **javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named entityManagerFactoryA** Do you know why?

Comment: Without checking your code it is impossible to know why, but most likely this is a misconfiguration issue (xml config not on classpath for ex)

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with new working solution:

```
EntityManager em = context.getBeansOfType(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class)
                          .getOrDefault("&entityManagerFactoryA", null)
                          .getNativeEntityManagerFactory()
                          .createEntityManager();
```

For some reason I need to prefix EntityManagerFactory key (name) with **&**.
I would appreciate any explanation why is this required?